# Smarty unable to load css file?

Tags: php, templates, smarty

So, I recently discover Smarty and I must say it's a pretty awesome template engine. Anywho, I will be working in this PHP CMS type of software.

I'm trying to have smarty work with the "userpanel/" directory and at the same time work with other template calls made from index.php in the "public_html" directory.

Current file structure.
/home/user/public_html/
./  ../  includes/  libs/  templates/  templates_c/  userpanel/

The index file for the "userpanel" directory.
user@userdomain.com [~/public_html/]# cat userpanel/index.php

```
<?php
require '../libs/Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->setTemplateDir('../templates');
$smarty->assign('title', 'My CMS');
$smarty->assign('page', 'home');
$smarty->display('userpanel/main.tpl');


?>
```

And here is the template structure.

```
/home/user/public_html/templates/
./  ../  userpanel/
```

"userpanel" is the template name.

```
/home/user/public_html/templates/userpanel
./  ../  content.tpl  css/  footer.tpl  header.tpl  main.tpl
```

Here is the code in main.tpl, the footer/header/content loads but without the CSS.

```
user@userdomain.com [~/public_html/templates/userpanel]# cat main.tpl 
<html>
<head>
<title>{$title}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
{include file='userpanel/header.tpl'}
{include file='userpanel/content.tpl'}
<br />
{include file='userpanel/footer.tpl'}
</body>
</html>
```

I tried "templates/userpanel/css/style.css" & "userpanel/css/style.css"

But those fails.

Anywho, to keep things short. What would be the best way for me to use Smarty for the admin panel & index.php file? And why is the CSS file not loading?

Thank you.